# How to use grep to retrieve matching text from a file?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a txt file like this:

```
asdfasdf
ffaCover 91adf
ffffa
```

I want to use grep or some linux tool to capture the 1 or 2 digits following the space after 'Cover'. In some programming languages I would use the regex library to match /^Cover (\d\d?)$/. Then there would be some way to get at the 1 or 2 digits inside the parenthesis. Is there a way to do this using grep?

Comment: `grep -o` or `cut -f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had always done something like this:

```
 grep -Po '(?<=Cover\s)(\d\d?)'
```

The `-o` option to `grep` makes it print out only the matching part of the pattern, which does not include the zero-width lookbehind assertion.

But, I did not know about the `\K` option in anubhava's answer before, which seems cleaner.

Comment: I ended up going with this because the Windows system I was on does not seem to support that \K option.

Answer (score 2):

Just pipe to `grep -oP`:

```
grep -Po 'Cover \K[0-9]{1,2}'
91
```

`\K` in PCRE regex resets all previously matched information.